# Error #1064 mysql update wordpress wp_posts - post_content phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Hi i have problem whit phpmyadmin version 4.5.1

I want replace a "word" in my old post database. For ex. I want replace

`xxx` with `yyy`

I try many code but I have this error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
 SET `post_content` = replace(post_content, 'xxx', 'yyy');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, ‘xxx’, ‘xxx’);
UPDATE wp_posts

SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'xxx', 'yyy')
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have curly quotes in your syntax?

Comment: i try whit '  or " and `

Comment: @dingo_d  you can write the correct version and try if it works?

Comment: I don't know why this shouldn't work (I'm a beginner at SQL), but in this line: `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, ‘xxx’, ‘xxx’);
` you have curly quotes when you're replacing post content with the same thing. Put regular quotes `'`

Comment: @dingo_d don't work error 1064

Comment: @dingo_d  now i try 
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'xxx', 'xxx');   
and 
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, ‘xxx’, ‘xxx’);

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using phpMyAdmin, I suggest that you use the search and replace feature.

From within your table, click the Search tab along the top, then under that the "Find and replace" link.

[image: Find and replace tab]

Next enter the text you want to search and the replacement,

[image: Search and replace dialog]

making sure to pick the correct "Column" from the dropdown.

You'll get a preview before completing the process.

Comment: At which part of the process exactly? Any hints in your webserver error log?